# Could not verify the SSL certificate for http://gemcutter.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I'm trying to make a bundle install and a rails server with an app I just received.

I don't understand, all the gem sources are http:// however i get a SSL error.

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LqB1.png)

In my Gemfile there are no source starting with https://

What I've already tried :

- remove Gemfile.lock
- --trust-policy=NoSecurity
- gem install rake -v '10.0.3' (command failed)

Thanks and sorry for my english

PS: I must run it on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/1554-ssl-issue-with-gemcutter) and [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-aws/commit/7a8b11328f0b5bae12795a6cbff8f405b6a683f9) thread gemcutter.org should redirect to rubygems.org. Just remove it from the sources and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to remove gemcutter source but I get "undefined method 'extensions' for nil:NilClass - An error occureced while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue." So I tried ton install rake 10.1.0 and it succed but bundler install keep failing. In the source the rake asked is 10.0.3 and so I don't understand why bundle install try to install the 10.1.0, it could me the problem ? Any idea ?

Comment: No idea about that but I think these are separate problems and you would be better off leaving gemcutter out and continuing troubleshooting the rake problem on its own.